# Using COUNTIFS or dcounta instead of multiple COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets

In our Staff timetable, employees can have an "A"shift (which starts at 9am) a "B" shift (which starts at 10:30am)  etc. 
I need to know how many shifts in total the employees make so what I use now is a multiple times COUNTIF to count the presents of a few arguments in a range of cells

```
=countif(D8:BM8;A43)+countif(D8:BM8;A44)+countif(D8:BM8;A45)+countif(D8:BM8;A46)++countif(D8:BM8;A47)
```

Where field A43 contains "A"  field A44 cointains "B"  etc.

This works perfect, however, I want to have a smarter way to do this, so I tried to use "COUNTIFS" but the result is always 0  and I can't find why

```
=COUNTIFS(D8:BM8;A43;D8:BM8;A44;D8:BM8;A45;D8:BM8;A46;D8:BM8;A47)
```

if looks like all arguments are checked with a logical and, but I need a logical and in this case or a solution with dcounta

Comment: posting an image would help us to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a 0 because there is no cell that will meet ALL conditions.
Instead, maybe try something like

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(--regexmatch(D8:BM8; textjoin("|"; 1; A43:A47))))
```

Regexmatch returns a boolean, for all the cells in D8:BM8 (true if a match is found, false otherwise). These booleans are converted into 1 and 0 (see the -- in front of the regex). Then all those values are summed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy and paste the code in a module.(VBA)
2. Select the cell you want to have the results
3. Use COUNTIFMATCH Function as the usally functions.
4. The first Argument is the range you want to count. The second Argument is the range with your criteria. e.g
   =COUNTIFMATCH($A$1:$A$20,$C$1:$C$3) or =COUNTIFMATCH($A$1:$A$20,($B$1,$D$1))
   whatever you need based on your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Function COUNTIFMATCH(Range As Range, Criteria As Range) As Integer

'counts the number of cells in one range by the values ​​of another range.

Dim datax As Range
Dim rslt As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set rslt = Range

For Each datax In Criteria

i = i + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rslt, datax)

COUNTIFMATCH = i

Next datax

End Function
```